# Regex code to match string start and end position, but exclude specific matches

Tags: regex

Can someone help, please! I have a list of account numbers, below is an example of the formats.
Essentially all accounts start with "DO", they then have four numbers, they then have a sibling account with an "M" on the end and another with a "PY".
DO1200, DO1200M, DO1200PY

I want to identify all accounts that end in "M" and have the following code to do that.

```
^DO.\[M\]$
```

I have 3 accounts I want to exclude from this list, DO1210M, DO1215M & DO1220M and I haven't been able to find an answer.

I've tried searching StackOverflow for other answers such as:

```
^/(?!DO1210M|DO1215M|DO1220M)(\[a-z0-9\]+)$
```

And trying to add this into my code, and while some of my attempts still retrieve results they never actually exclude the accounts I'm trying to exclude.

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using regex in Jedox, I'm not sure if that helps?

Comment: It lets us know what you can and can't do. Many people are using a programming language like Python or PHP which gives them more flexibility than just being tied to a single regex solution.

Comment: I don't think you want the backslashes before the brackets `[` and `]`. That should be telling the regex to treat those as literal brackets, not the enclosing a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead with a non capturing group:

```
^(?!(?:DO1210M|DO1215M|DO1270M)$)^DO\d{4}M$
^                                ^              #beginning of the line
                               $          $     #end of line
 (?!                            )               #negative lookahead
    (?:                       )                 #non capturing group
              |       |                         #logical OR
       XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX                  #text not to match
                                  DO     M      #Literal text
                                    \d          #any digit
                                      {4}       #quantifier, exactly 4 times
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/IH73NI/1)